# Jest and Typescript - Test if "Array.prototype.reverse()" has been called

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test a function that contains a call to the Array.prototype.reverse function in an array.

I have trouble spying on the "reverse" function. I cannot get the parameters for the jest.spyOn function correct.

This is similar to the actual code I'm trying to test:

```
const parentFunction = (param) => {
    let someArray = [];
    switch(param) {
        case 1:
            someArray = childFunction();
            break;
        default:
            break;        
    }
    return someArray;
}

const childFunction = () => {
    const anotherArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const reversedArray = anotherArray.reverse();
    return reversedArray;
}
```

And this is my test so far:

```
test("if the reverse function has been called", () => {
    jest.spyOn(Array, "reverse"); // this shows an error in the editor
    jest.spyOn(Array.prototype, "reverse"); // this also shows an error in the editor

    parentFunction(1);
    expect(Array.reverse).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(Array.prototype.reverse).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The word "reverse" gets underlined in red in my editor (VS Code) and shows this error message:

```
No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(object: any\[\], method: FunctionPropertyNames\<any\[\]\>): never', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionPropertyNames\<any\[\]\>'.   Overload 2 of 4, '(object: any\[\], method: ConstructorPropertyNames\<any\[\]\>): never', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorPropertyNames\<any\[\]\>'.
```

Am I missing any unusual imports for testing this function?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't test _implementation_, test _behaviour_ - `expect(parent(1)).toEqual([4, 3, 2, 1]);`.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, the thing is that I don't know the contents of the array, so I don't know what the outcome would be, therefore your solution doesn't apply. Sorry for not specifying that before.
Do you have any other suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your `spy` instance, not directly on the object.

```
test("if the reverse function has been called", () => {
  const reverseSpy = jest.spyOn(Array.prototype, "reverse");
  parentFunction(1);
  expect(reverseSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```